# Unrecognized selector sent to instance while trying to open apple maps app in my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector, apple-maps

I am trying to open up apple maps within the map that I created, and in the process of doing so I am getting an error saying that "unrecognized selector send to instance". I am using arc so there should be no memory management problem. Here is the code I wrote in viewDidLoad. I created a button and added a selector to it..

```
UIButton *appleMapsButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
appleMapsButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200);
appleMapsButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[appleMapsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(appleMapsClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[mapView addSubview:appleMapsButton];
```

Here is the action method:

```
-(void)appleMapsClicked{

CLLocationCoordinate2D endingCoord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng);
MKPlacemark *endLocation = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:endingCoord addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem *endingItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:endLocation];

NSMutableDictionary *launchOptions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[launchOptions setObject:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving forKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey];

[endingItem openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
}
```

Here is the error I am getting in the debugger area:

-[MapViewController appleMapsClicked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x176564d0
2016-04-15 16:10:39.394 Restaurant[1081:220822] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MapViewController appleMapsClicked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x176564d0'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are registering to receive the message with the method `appleMapsClicked:`, but your method does not have a parameter.

Removing the :, or changing the method signature to `-(void)appleMapsClicked:(id)sender` should fix it.

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me most of the time. The best way to clear this error which is suppose to "not to happen in the the first place", is:

1) Delete your UIButton and the IBOutlet
2) Create a new UIButton again and reconnect to the ViewController.

To find out if this is the problem, delete all of your codes inside button function and run. If you press the button and still it makes an error, then you just have to create a fresh button.

This might be a solution for some.

Answer (score 1):

You probably renamed or removed a button that invokes appleMapsClicked on MapViewController.

Same thing happened to me, but I could not fix it the conventional ways, (right clicking on the button and removing the method reference from UI)

Then I could fix the problem by opening Main.StoryBoard using an external editor (right click on Main.StoryBoard and click "open using an external editor").

It will open the storyboard as an XML file. At the editor, search for "appleMapsClicked" under the MapViewController node. The first thing you may find is a reference to a method (appleMapsClicked) that does not exist anymore. Delete the line and run again.

This may sound as a nasty solution, as you should not be messing with auto-generated files with Xcode, but that was my only way out.

I hope it helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Found Solution:

When you are adding a method as a selector and the method has no parameters do not place the colon beside the method like so:

```
(mySelector:)
```

By excluding the colon, the app did not crash.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions:

1. Change the method `-(void)appleMapsClicked` with `-(void)appleMapsClicked:(UIButton *)sender`
2. Change the name of selector `@selector(appleMapsClicked:)` with `@selector(appleMapsClicked)`

You can choose anyone of those solutions